# restrict qualifier on member functions (restrict this pointer)

Tags: c++, gcc, this-pointer, restrict-qualifier

**Note:** To clarify, the question is not about the use of the `restrict` keyword in general, but specifically about applying it to member functions as described [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html#Restricted-Pointers).

gcc allows you to use the `__restrict__` (the GNU++ equivalent to C99's `restrict`) qualifier on a member function, effectively making `this` a restrict qualified pointer within the function's scope. Where is the beef?

Most member functions work on other members, accessing them via `this`, which is a `T* const` (and normally unaliased). For `this` to be possibly aliased, there would need to be a second pointer-to-type in use within the member function somehow, and it would have to come from somewhere.
That is a situation which is regularly the case with non-member functions, such as for example all binary operators or any other free function that takes at least two pointers or references of an identical, non-trivial type. However, these functions don't have a `this`, so they're not relevant.

The assignment operator, copy constructor, and unary comparison operators are examples of member functions where `this` *could*  in principle be aliased (since another object is passed via reference). So it only really makes sense to assign a restrict qualifier to these -- it should already be obvious to the compiler that all other functions have the restrict property anyway (because there is never a second pointer-to-T).

Now, if for example you used `restrict` on `operator=` you should *consequentially* not check for self-assignment at all, because you're saying that `this` is not aliased within the scope of that function (and *if that's true*, no self-assignment can possibly happen).
Obviously, this is something that you cannot possibly know in advance, and it's something that doesn't make sense either.

So, what would be a case where one would actually want to give a member function a restrict qualifier and where it makes sense?

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to do so. What exactly would you be de-aliasing with `this` - it's not really a continuous array of a same type?

Comment: @Anycom: If the class has data members, any compatible pointer may alias a data member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either I am missing something, or your question does not make sense.  `this` is not *that* different from any other argument to a member function, so why are you surprised that GCC allows you to apply `restrict` to it?

Regarding applying it to an assignment operator, you rightly point out that it would obviate the need for an explicit self-assignment test.  Then you say:

> Obviously, this is something that you cannot possibly know in advance

But this is *always* true when you use `restrict` for anything.  For example, somebody might decide to call `memcpy` with overlapping memory regions; you "cannot possibly know in advance" that they will not do so.  But the `restrict` declaration for the arguments of `memcpy` means *they have committed an error if they do*.  In exactly the same way, if you declare an assignment operator `restrict`, you have made it an error for someone to self-assign objects of that class.  There is nothing mysterious or contradictory about this at all; it is just part of the semantics of `restrict` that it imposes certain constraints on the rest of your code.

I am also not sure why you find it so impossible for a member function to take a pointer (or reference) to another object of the same type.  Trivial example:

```
class Point {
public:
    double distance(const Point &other) const;
};
```

This sort of thing crops up all the time.

So the real question is, why do you think `this` is so different from any other argument?  Or if you prefer, how did I miss your point so completely?

Answer (score 2):

I belive what you guys are missing is that an argument to a member function could also alias **parts** or an object. Here's an example

```
struct some_class {
    int some_value;

    void compute_something(int& result) {
        result = 2*some_value;
        ...
        result -= some_value;
    }
}
```

One would probably expect that to compile to

```
*(this + offsetof(some_value)) -> register1
2*register1 -> register2
...
register2 - register1 -> result
```

That code, unfortunately, would be **wrong** if someone passes a reference to some_value for result. Thus, a compiler would actually need to generate to following

```
*(this + offsetof(some_value)) -> register1
2*register1 -> register2
register2 -> result

...
*(this + offsetof(some_value)) -> register1
result -> register2
register2 - register1 -> register2
register2 -> result
```

which is obviously way less efficient. Note that unless compute_something is inlines, the compiler has **no** way of knowing whether result may alias some_value or not, so it **has** to assume the worst case, no matter no smart or dumb it is. So there a definite and very real advantage to restrict, even if applied to the this pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted is interesting. There will not be a solid use case for having `restrict` applied on `this`. As you mentioned in your question, *copy constructor, operator =* could have been potential candidates; but compiler can take care of them.

But following case can be interesting

```
struct A
{
  //...
  void Destroy (A*& p) __restrict__
  {
    delete this;
    p = 0;
    p++;
  }
};
```

Now use case can be;

```
A **pp = new A*[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  pp[i] = new A;
//...
A* p = pp[0];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  p->Destroy(p);
delete[] pp;
```

Though this is very unusual practice, this is the only case I could think of this use case.

Comment: Heh, funny example, though I think that's not even "unusual", but rather something one would want to avoid, both for being somewhat non-obvious and having weird semantics. The semantics would be somewhat like "given any _different_ pointer-to-object of which I assert it's not my object, destroy _my object_ anyway, and modify the pointer to some other object".

Comment: @Damon, that's correct; but compiler may not differ between obvious and non-obvious. Anyways, restricting `this` pointer doesn't make much sense to me. Let see if someone has any better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I don't clearly understand why you're talking about `this`.

`restrict` specifies that a pointer is not overlapped with others. So, compilers can assume the memory regions pointed by restrict pointers are not dependent, which allows more aggressive optimizations. `__restrict__` would be much more effective when used for other pointer variables than `this`.

> So, what would be a case where one would actually want to give a
>   member a restrict qualifier and where it makes sense?

Just recall a representative case of using `restrict` pointers in `memcpy`:

```
void Foo::MyCompute(__restrict__ char* bufA, __restrict__ char* BufB)
{
}
```

Comment: See the last two paragraphs [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html#Restricted-Pointers). I am aware of the use of `restrict` for function parameters or within blocks, which is of course entirely clear. My question is about giving `this` restrict qualification (as described in the linked documentation), which does not seem to make sense at all to me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer, because it's probably better suited as such (it's kind of an answer and doesn't really belong to the question, plus it's a bit long for a comment).

After thinking about Nemo's answer for a long time, I believe that our both interpretation about self-assignment is maybe somewhat wrong (though Nemo's was more correct than mine). As Nemo correctly pointed out, having a restrict-qualified `this` actually means that presence of aliasing is a program error. No more, no less.

Insofar, when writing this, your logic should actually not be "since you say this cannot happen, you consequentially should not check for self-assignment", but rather "since you explicitly say that aliasing cannot happen, and it's a program error if it does, you *not only* need to check for self-assignment, but you consequentially *must* fail hard if it happens".

And, insofar, it emphasizes a particular program logic and at the same time allows the compiler to optimize better for that particular special case, and thus *does indeed make sense*.