# How to apply restrict qualifier on this pointer

Tags: c++, class, this, restrict-qualifier

How can I apply GCC's/Clang's `__restrict__` qualifier to the `this` pointer of a class?
This question was inspired by Richard Powell's CppCon 2018 talk, "[How to Argue(ment).](https://youtu.be/ZbVCGCy3mGQ?t=775)" I saw a similar question "[restrict qualifier on member functions (restrict this pointer).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808472/restrict-qualifier-on-member-functions-restrict-this-pointer)" (All code can be found on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WuDktp))

```
void bar();

class Foo {
 public:
  int this_example() const {
    if (value > 0) {
      bar();
      return value;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }

 private:
  int value;
};
```

The above code generates the following assembly. In it, we can see that `value` has to be loaded twice, via the `this` pointer. This makes sense, it is a consequence that C++ inherited from C and the [restrict qualifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) allows the programmer to turn off the behavior. I can find no way to enable the `restrict` functionality for the `this` pointer.

```
Foo::this_example() const:               # @Foo::this_example() const
        push    rbx
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        test    eax, eax
        jle     .LBB2_2
        mov     rbx, rdi
        call    bar()
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbx]
.LBB2_2:
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

On the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WuDktp) page, I show examples of method arguments using `__restrict__` to elide the second load. There is also an example of passing a struct reference to a function and using `__restrict__` to elide the second load.

I can imagine a world where the compiler would allow the programmer to mention the implicit `this` pointer in the arguments of a method. The compiler could then allow application of qualifiers to the `this` pointer. See code below for an example.

```
class Foo {
 public:
  int unrestricted(Foo *this);
  int restricted(Foo *__restrict__ this);
};
```

As a follow up question, is there something in the C++ standard or a C++ guideline that would make it so that `this` could never have the restrict qualifier?

Comment: How about putting the entire implementation of `this_example` into a static member function, with `restrict`ed `const Foo *` parameter?

Comment: Even if you apply it to `this`, this still does not guarantee that `bar` does not change `value`. Also it will still have to be loaded again because of function calling convention.

Comment: @Ivan Yes, but that would be UB. The compiler would optimize based on an assumption that would never happen, which is what OP wants, it seems.

Comment: For better or worse, `restrict` is just not the part of C++. So there is nothing in standards.

Comment: @Ivan, why would it need to be loaded again?

Comment: @SergeyA I didn't understand the question. I though OP wanted it to be loaded again. Although I still don't understand it. Is it about applying `restrict` globally?

Comment: @Ivan, Thank you for your comment. I am looking for a way to tell the compiler that, for a specific method call, the data pointed to by `this` will not be changed by some other piece of code; that it can't see. Some C++ compilers allow this behavior via restrict, but only for function/method arguments that can be explicitly stated in the definition.

Comment: @cmwt Isn't your question then duplicates [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808472/restrict-qualifier-on-member-functions-restrict-this-pointer) you linked? One of the answers even has code example, although no the accepted answer.

Comment: @Ivan, They are similar. The other OP asks, "...what would be a case where one would actually want to give a member function a restrict qualifier...?" I was asking how to apply the restrict qualifier specifically to the the `this` pointer because I am trying to get the compiler to elide the second load. I thought it was different enough to warrant its own question. I am sorry if it is not. I am new to programming and Stack Overflow.  @Acorn answered the question but all the compilers I have tested still preform the second load even with the restrict qualifier on the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GCC's documentation for `__restrict__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html) (as well as the linked question) mentions that you can actually restrict `this`:

> You may also specify whether a member function’s `this` pointer is unaliased by using `__restrict__` as a member function qualifier.
>
> ```
> void T::fn () __restrict__
> {
>     /* … */
> }
> ```
>
> Within the body of `T::fn`, `this` has the effective definition `T *__restrict__ const this`. Notice that the interpretation of a `__restrict__` member function qualifier is different to that of `const` or `volatile` qualifier, in that it is applied to the pointer rather than the object. This is consistent with other compilers that implement restricted pointers.

Note, however, that marking the `this` pointer as such does not prevent the second load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You beat me to it. After two days I found the site you mentioned in your answer. I tried your answer in Compiler Explorer and neither Clang or GCC elide the second load. I guess I'll have to do some more digging.